# Using Rows/Row twice in xslt

Tags: 2013, list, list-view, xslt

I want to use Rows/Row twice but I have no idea how to do it. So I just wrote Rows/Li but it 
doesn't work.

I have two different functions but I don't know how to reference them.

How can I change **Rows/Li** line and any helpful link for a document about it will be good for me? Thank you.

I want this:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
</ol>
```

But I get this:`<ol class="carousel-indicators"></ol>`

My code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">

    <xsl:output method='html' indent='yes'/>

    <xsl:template match='dsQueryResponse' xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" ddwrt:ghost="" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls">
      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide  bt-nav-mar" data-ride="carousel"> 

        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <xsl:apply-templates select='Rows/Li'/>
        </ol>   
        <div class="carousel-inner">          
            <xsl:apply-templates select='Rows/Row'/>

        </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev"> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> 
            </a> 
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next"> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> 
            </a>    

    </div> 


    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match='Li'>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" >
            <xsl:attribute name="data-slide-to">
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>     

    <xsl:template match='Row'>

         <div class="item"> 
         <a href="/../Lists/Duyurular/DispForm.aspx?ID={string(@ID)}"  class="fontText">

            <img alt="gallery thumbnail" ><xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Picture"></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:attribute></img>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3><xsl:value-of select="@Title" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></h3>
              <p><xsl:value-of select="@Body" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></p>
            </div>
          </a>
         </div>


     </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: XSLT is case-sensitive. Are you sure the list items are called `Li` in the source XML? Maybe you should try `li` or `LI`.

Comment: Have you managed to make it work?

Comment: No I couldn't make it work. I try to find a similar code but there isn't :/

Comment: So, I guess my hint did not work?

Comment: No. Sorry for I did not give any feedback.